# Continuously read from a pipe in C

Tags: c, pipe

I need to develop a program that I have 10 child processes that each processes a part of an array and whenever a number that is bigger than 20 is found in that part the process writes it to the pather process via a pipe.

So far I've come up with this to write in the pipe:

```
for (i = 0; i < CHILDS; i++)
    {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] == 0)
        {
            for (j = 5000 * i; j < (5000 * i) + 5000; j++)
            {
                if (array[j].quantity > 20)
                {
                    write(fd[1], &array[j].product_code, sizeof(array[j].product_code));
                }
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

How can I countinously read from that pipe in the father process and whenever he reads something write it onto an array?

I've tried this but isn't working:

```
    while ((p_code = read(fd[0], &p_code, sizeof(p_code))) > 0)
    {
        products[i] = p_code;
        i++;
    }
```

Thank You :D

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean?  Is it blocking?  Is `read` returning an error?  Is `read` returning unexpected data?  Did the parent (not "father") close the file descriptors?

Comment: Ack: `p_code( read( ..., p_code, ...))` is not correct.  You are reading data into p_code and then over-writing it with the return value.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it was writting the same data over and over again in the products array. I got it fixed now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the pipe incorrectly.  Replace:

```
 while ((p_code = read(fd[0], &p_code, sizeof(p_code))) > 0)
```

with

```
ssize_t rc;
while ((rc = read(fd[0], &p_code, sizeof p_code)) > 0)
```

You ought not overwrite the data you just read with the value returned by `read`.

Also, you'll want to check if rc < 0 to catch any errors, check the return value of `write` for errors, and make sure the parent has closed `fd[1]` (unless you need it for something you haven't shown, that is).

Comment: Well you sir got it right! Thanks a lot, that solved it!